# How to add or remove nodes dynamically when children's fetching from remote

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treeview

```
   <kendo-treeview #departmentTree [nodes]="departmentList" textField="EnName" kendoTreeViewExpandable
                  kendoTreeViewSelectable kendoTreeViewHierarchyBinding [hasChildren]="hasChildren"
                  [children]="fetchChildren" (nodeClick)="onNodeClick($event)">
                  <ng-template kendoTreeViewNodeTemplate let-dataItem>
                    <span class="tree-node">
                      {{dataItem.EnName}} </span>
                  </ng-template>
                </kendo-treeview>
```

```
  public fetchChildren = (node: any): Observable < any[] > => {
    return this.httpService.getDepartment(node.DepartmentId);
  }
```

i want to insert new nodes into existing treeview  without refresh. (like push into the existing array ) i try to push child nodes into selected dataItem 
`this.selectedNode.items.push(newItem)`
i didn't find any documentation for this

Comment: Where is the code for pushing into `selectedNode.items`?

Comment: actually i want to know that exacly where the child node array they stored when we fetch child from remote

Answer (score 0):

> i want to insert new nodes into existing treeview

The whole idea behind front-end frameworks, including Angular, is to change data and let the framework change the view, using a declarative template provided by you (as `@Component#template` or `@Component#templateUrl`).

> without refresh

Everything in a single-page application is done without refresh. That's the whole point and that's why they're called *single-page* applications: there is no notion of traditional pages that the browser fetches from the server: all changes are done via client-site JavaScript, including the “page” changes made by a JavaScript implementation of a router (the common choice is `@angular/router`).

> (like push into the existing array )

That's precisely what you have to do. Angular will handle updating the view, unless the component is built incorrectly or heavily optimized and thus requires a manual change detection cycle trigger, but you'd probably know when these cases arise, so I don't think you have to worry about that yet.

> i try to push child nodes into selected dataItem  this.selectedNode.items.push(newItem)

Something else is wrong then. Try printing the whole array as a JSON to the page to see if it's changing: `{{ selectedNode.items | json }}`.

---

I'll update the answer with a concrete reason why you're not seeing the view changed when you add the missing details. The above is the general idea which could help others better understand why the view might not be updating.

Comment: Thank you and please consider kendo treeview dataItems doesn't have children's (items[]) array even after fetch the children when i print console the node or all dataSource so i want to know where they keeping child node arrays once  its fetched from remote